# What are some possible causes of failure in automatic email sends from User Import?

Tags: emails

In a D7 (up to date) site where the User Import module had been working successfully, it is now generating an error for email-sends and failing to send the Welcome Email that should result from importing a .csv list of users. Tried several email addresses as a test, they did not send. It was working for several years but a lot of things have been updated since then – core and numerous modules. I don't see any details in the site log that clearly define the nature of the error. [The error message in Log is just "Error sending e-mail (from info@our-org.org to name-of-recipient.com)."]

Using the "send test email" option of the SMTP Authentication Support module seems to verify there's nothing wrong with that. I tried going back several versions for both the SMTP Authentication Support and User Import modules but nothing improved. What are some other things to check which could be related to the failure?

==Thanks==

**Update:** When one stumbles upon a solution, of course it's a relief to have the problem solved but it's dissatisfying when it's not understood exactly what happened. I did not have the Mailsystem module installed, only SMTP Authentication Support and as mentioned, that had been working. I installed Mailsystem to see if maybe that would work better. It did not, but... if I have *both* SMTP Authentication *AND* Mailsystem installed, with Mailsystem's config set to "SmtpMailSystem" as the default Delivery method – then it works. Glad it works of course. But the problem is, I don't understand what's really going on since only one module was previously required to make it work.

Comment: We can't tell... There is an endless list of things that can cause this. Perhaps you have the [mailsystem module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) installed and are not actually using the SMTP module (for those mails). Try going through webserver logs, mailserver logs (if you have access to them). Try to figure out when the problem occured and what was changed just before that. Since we cannot see your configuration, we cannot pinpoint the cause of trouble. If you have more details, or a suspicion, provide those in the question. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Neograph734, thanks and please see the Update added above. You can take credit for just mentioning the Mailsystem module, since that led to a solution although probably in a very different way than imagined.

Comment: I am happy to hear that your problem is solved, but I have no idea why it would work now... It could be that SMTP had and update and is no longer listening to the drupal mail event, but it does listen to mailsystem. If that is the case you might find a clue in the SMTP issue queue on Drupal.org. Other than that I have no idea.